# "Inbox" and "Achievements" buttons available on iPad without login

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

**Description:**

On iPad, the "Inbox" and "Achievements" buttons are available even without login.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Start the Stack Exchange app on iPad.
2. On the front page, tap "Start using without account".
3. On the left bar, the 3rd button (Inbox) and the 4th button (Achievements) are visible, even if I have not logged in.

   1. If I tap on the "Inbox" button, nothing happens.
   2. If I tap on the "Achievements" button, it shows a popup box and the error: "**Request failed.** Tap to retry."

**Actual Results:**

The "Inbox" and "Achievements" buttons are visible even without login.

**Expected Results:**

The "Inbox" and "Achievements" buttons should be hidden if not logged in, as in the iPhone version.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v1.1.0.118
- iPad 2
- iOS 8.0

Comment: Great catch! We normally leave anonymous mode testing to do after we're done with everything else, this should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was one of those Friday afternoons *oops* moments which was fixed but never pushed out to our beta users. Thanks for catching it though! Shows you guys are paying attention.

It should be now fixed as of version **1.1.0.119**.

Comment: Verified fixed in 1.1.0.123.